# Confused about Kibana import

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana-4, bitnami, warc

I would like to know about how I can import data using kibana. Actually, its a confusion for me. I have tried to load json file using kibana, but it is not importing it.
second, if I want to work with Warc file, they do I need to convert it into JSON file and then import it or is there any other solution that I need to work on.
Hope to hear a reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your JSON file directly to elasticsearch and later on create an index from kibana application. You can run the following command:

`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @file.json`

About the second question, I think you need to convert to a JSON file first.

Comment: Thomas, I have tried this, but it is not working on my side. Trust me, I have done all the attempts, but all were in wasted.. If you have any other solution or idea, please share with me. Hope to hear from you soon... Actually I also read about Pentaho, but it has compatibility issues